# Append row in DataFrame pandas from function

Tags: python, dataframe, global-variables

I have a problem with adding row to DataFrame from my function, I get the same Data without any changes. But without function it works great and add row.

```
d = pd.DataFrame(orders).transpose().fillna(0)

def add_to_data(orders):
    to_add = pd.Series(orders)
    global d
    d.append(to_add, ignore_index=True).fillna(0)
    return d
```

Comment: Did you find an answer?